# Programmatically get node's Namespace

Tags: c++, libroscpp, namespace, node, roscpp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there a way to get a node's current namespace?

Say I launch a node like this

```
<launch>
<group ns="robot_1">
<node pkg="myrobot" type="robot" name="robot"/>
</group>
</launch>
```

then this node is really called `/robot_1/robot`. Now what if it should publish something on a topic whose name depends on the namespace?

So in this case the topic may be `/robot_1/control`.

Is there a way I can get my code to dynamically find this namespace?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/62620/programmatically-get-node%27s-namespace/) by [Claudio](https://answers.ros.org/users/3152/claudio/) on ROS Answers with karma: 859 on 2013-05-13

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [SL Remy](https://answers.ros.org/users/1001/sl-remy/) on 2013-05-13**:
Do you mean that you'd prefer to select that the node publishes  in `/robot_1/robot` instead of `/robot`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If something needs to subscribe to the `control` topic, if it is in the same namespace as the `robot` node then subscribing to `control` will automatically find the `/robot_1/control` topic.  Subscribing to `/control` will not automatically find the one you want.  More can be read [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/Names).

Also note that if for some reason you need to get the namespace of a particular node from within that node you can do this in both  `roscpp` and `rospy` using

```
std::string ns = ros::this_node::getNamespace();
```

and

```
ns = rospy.get_namespace()
```

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2013-05-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 20

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Claudio](https://answers.ros.org/users/3152/claudio/) on 2013-05-13**:
Thanks Jarvis, that was exactly what I needed.